# Angular Http Interceptor - fromPromise error - TypeError: (0 , x.fromPromise) is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

I am use the function below to attach recaptcha v3 to Http Request.

```
@Injectable()
export class RecaptchaInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private recaptchaService: ReCaptchaService) { }

intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {    
  return fromPromise(this.recaptchaService.execute({ action: 'login' }))
    .pipe(switchMap(token => {
      const headers = httpRequest.headers
        .set('recaptcha', token)
      const reqClone = httpRequest.clone({
        headers
      });
      return next.handle(reqClone);
    }));
}
```

In localhost this is work fine, But from some reason after publish I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: (0 , x.fromPromise) is not a function
> TypeError: (0 , x.fromPromise) is not a function

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use from instead of fromPromise because i think you are using rxjs 6+

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

...
return from(this.recaptchaService.execute({ action: 'login' }))
```

Comment: Well, it really solved the problem, Thanks you! Do you know to explain why? What the different between them?

Comment: no diff, fromPromise  is replaced by from in rxjs 6. fromPromise   is not part of their APi any more

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks!